# Good design pattern choice for initializing a hashmap in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, hashmap

I have a non-static class in Java that has a static hashmap field. The hashmap should be initialized with some key-value pairs generated by code. The hashmap is not to be changed after that.

How should this be achieved? Should I just create a static init method and make sure to run this once before using the class, or are there better ways of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a static initializer block in your class.

e.g.

```
private static Map<String, String> myMap;
static {
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("foo","bar");

    myMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

Comment: The type of the `map` variable should be `Map`, not HashMap.

Comment: @VGR "should" is a strong word here given that there is no tangible value to changing it in the above code.  Would save some key strokes though so no real objection either.  The class member variable is appropriately a `Map`, it is only the short lived block scoped `map` variable that is declared as a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create immutable maps with Google Guava library:

```
private static Map<String, String> map = ImmutableMap.of(
    "key1", "value1",
    "key2", "value2");
```

If you want to use it for many values then `builder()` is provided.